# Perl - initialization of hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm not sure how to correctly initialize my hash - I'm trying to create a key/value pair for values in coupled lines in my input file.

For example, my input looks like this:

```
@cluster t.18
46421 ../../../output###.txt/
@cluster t.34
41554 ../../../output###.txt/
```

I'm extracting the t number from line 1 (@cluster line) and matching it to output###.txt in the second line (line starting with 46421). However, I can't seem to get these values into my hash with the script that I have written.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $key;
my $value;
my %hash;

my $filename = 'input.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        if ($line =~ m/^\@cluster/) {
            my @fields = split /(\d+)/, $line;
            my $key = $fields[1];          
        }
        elsif ($line =~ m/^(\d+)/) { 
            my @output = split /\//, $line;
            my $value = $output[5];       
}          
        $hash{$key} = $value;
}
```

Comment: Drop the `my` from `my $key` and `my $value` in the `if/elsif` blocks because that will create _new_ variables and hide the global ones. But what's the expected outcome? `{1 => 'output###.txt', 2 => 'output###.txt'}` ?

Comment: @PerlDog Thanks for the feedback. Yes, the hash I would like is `{1 => 'output###.txt', 2 => 'output###.txt'}` - I would just add a counter, but the numbers aren't in order in my input file.

Comment: Ok, and how does the `1` in line 1 relate to the `1111` in line 2? Why do they match? Because the 2nd line starts with 4 times the number from line 1 or because it's `number + 1110`? Or simply because it's the next line? Please show some input that is not as ambiguous.

Comment: @PerlDog, I tried to simplify the input I posted in the question but here are the first few lines of the actual input                                         `@cluster t.10 has 4319 elements, 0 subclusters
37652 ../../../../clust/output43888.txt 1.397428
` Basically the number in the second line is an arbitrary identifier then it's the output file (output###.txt) and last is a distance measurement.

Comment: @EA00  Thank you for the attribution.  Please note that I've added a comment at the end which may be helpful.  If you show your actual data (a few lines), I can also add some code to back up that comment.

Comment: @zdim Yes, you are right - using a regex would make parsing more clear - thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @EA00  I now see your comment just above -- (1) you need the number after `t.`, so `10` (2) what do you need from the other line, in the example in your comment above?

Comment: @zdim From the second line I just need the name of the output file "output###.txt"

Comment: @EA00  I added some examples of how to do it with regex. Note that there are, of course, yet other ways to do that -- and/or to organize the parsing of a pair of lines.

Comment: @EA00  Btw, I generally reach for `split` first, unless a regex is specifically called for. It's just that in this case you need the _delimiter_ itself in the first line, and very precise counting in the second, which is why I brought up regex.  While, in fact, I often find myself suggesting a simple `split` instead of some crazy complex regex :)

Comment: @zdim Thank you so much for taking the time to not only help me with my problem, but to also teach me about perl. The regex definitely simplified the script, and made it more efficient - I just tend to shy away from using them, as they are sometimes intimidating to implement, at least for a beginner like myself.

Comment: @EA00 You are most welcome. You are working on what you bring up, absorbing new things, and it's a pleasure to help out a little. Regex are a bit specific, I agree. (And they can get very involved, too, turning into a separate little language.) I would suggest though to get the basics down as that is something that you do use daily, when comfortable with it.  It's one of the things that should be in your toolbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a good idea, but your `$key` that is created with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) in the `if` *block* is a local variable scoped to that block, masking the global `$key`.  Inside the `if` block the symbol `$key` has nothing to do with the one you nicely declared upfront. See [`my in perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29).

This local `$key` goes out of scope as soon as `if` is done and does not exist outside the `if` block. The global `$key` is again available after the `if`, being visible elsewhere in the loop, but is undefined since it has never been assigned to. The same goes for `$value` in the `elsif` *block*.

Just drop the `my` declaration inside the loop, thus assign to those global variables (as intended?). So, `$key = ...` and `$value = ...`, and the hash will be assigned correctly.

---

Note -- this is about how to get that hash assignment right. I don't know how your actual data looks and whether the line is parsed correctly.  Here is a toy `input.txt`

```
@cluster t.1 
1111 ../../../output1.1.txt/
@cluster t.2 
2222 ../../../output2.2.txt/
```

I pick the 4th field instead of the 6th, `$value = $output[3];`, and add

```
print "$_ => $hash{$_}\n" for keys %hash;
```

after the loop. This prints

```
1 => output1.1.txt
2 => output2.2.txt
```

I am not sure whether this is what you want but the hash is built fine.

---

*A comment on choice of tools in parsing*

You parse the lines for numbers, by using the property of [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to return the separators as well, when they are captured. That is neat, but in some sense it reverses its main purpose, which is to extract *other* components from the string, as delimited by the pattern. Thus it may make the purpose of the code a little bit convoluted, and you also have to index very precisely to retrieve what you need.

Instead of using `split` to extract the delimiter itself, which is given by a regex, why not extract it by a regex? That makes the intention crystal clear, too. For example, with input

```
@cluster t.10 has 4319 elements, 0 subclusters 
37652 ../../../../clust/output43888.txt 1.397428
```

the parsing can go as

```
if ($line =~ m/^\@cluster/) {
    ($key) = $line =~ /t\.(\d+)/;
}   
elsif ($line =~ m/^(\d+)/) { 
    ($value) = $line =~ m|.*/(\w+\.txt)|;
}    
$hash{$key} = $value if defined $key and defined $value;
```

where `t\.` and `\.txt` are added to more precisely specify the targets. If the target strings aren't certain to have that precise form, just capture `\d+`, and in the second case all non-space after the last `/`, say by `m|^\d+.*/(\S+)|`. We use the greediness of `.*`, which matches *everything* possible up to the thing that comes after it (a `/`), thus all the way to the very last `/`.

Then you can also reduce it to a single regex for each line, for example

```
if ($line =~ m/^\@cluster\s+t\.(\d+)/) {
    $key = $1;
}
elsif ($line =~ m|^\d+.*/(\w+\.txt)|) {
    $value = $1;
}
```

Note that I've added a condition to the hash assignment. The original code in fact assigns an `undef` on the first iteration, since no `$value` had yet been seen at that point. This is overwritten on the next iteration and we don't see it if we only print the hash afterwards.  The condition also guards you against failed matches, for malformatted lines or such.  Of course, far better checks can be run.

Comment: @PerlDog the splitting works for me in extracting the number and output for each respective line - I just can't get the hash to initialize. However, your suggestion for dropping the my works! Thanks!

Comment: @zdim I was trying to figure out how to print the hash - so thank you. Also, your explanation makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @PerlDog  Fair point, thank you, I've changed the offending statement to say that the hash is fine, not all else.  (However, note what I added -- split actually does pick up the number.) I'll fix the parsing as well.  Thank you.

Comment: @PerlDog  On the contrary.  The `split` may well be suitable for the actual data, but it is not best for what is shown, in my opinion -- it relies on `split` keeping the captured pattern and then plucks that by index, thus reversing the main purpose of `split`. If we want numbers I wouldn't `split` on numbers and count indices -- I think a regex would be far clearer.

Comment: @EA00 For printing hashes (or any other data structures) you may have a look at [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html). It's a core module written for that very purpose.

Comment: @PerlDog  I've cleaned up some as well, remove more if you wish and I'll follow.  (Will monitor this.) Thank you again for the constructive comment, I had added that and then also expanded the answer along those lines.